# Can't transpile typescript due to d3 event error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript, webpack

I have a d3 scatterplot chart in an Angular 2 project using typescript and webpack. Part of the chart responds to a mouseover event to display a tooltip. Now the mouseover event actually fires perfectly well, however I see an error when webpack transpiles the typescript.

```
 Property 'pageX' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'.
```

Here is a snippet showing the mouseover part of the chart element and the offending `d3.event.pageX`.

```
  .on("mouseover", (d: any) => {
    if(d.roleName) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("display", "block")
        .style("opacity", 1);
      div.html(d.roleName + "<br/>"  + d.org.name)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-80) + "px");
    }
  })
```

I am relatively new to typescript but gather the above issue may be something to do with the d3 typings file not mapping correctly?

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With d3 not being an actual TypeScript library we get .d.ts files to describe the original library. In this case it can't know that inside the on("mouseover" that d3.event actually means an MouseEvent, so you can try casting it to another type or ignore this little part from the compiler:

```
.on("mouseover", (d: any) => {
  if(d.roleName) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("display", "block")
      .style("opacity", 1);
    div.html(d.roleName + "<br/>"  + d.org.name)
      .style("left", ((<any>d3.event).pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", ((<any>d3.event).pageY-80) + "px");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3/d3.d.ts

interfaces `Event|BaseEvent` have **NOT** properties `pageX|pageY`.

Probably you should open an issue.

Comment: that is precisely the issue.. ie. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/4590 it seems a PR to address it was merged last year https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/4623 but the code is changed.